# HTML/CSS background with several vector shapes and no img

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

i know that there are a few questions like this, but non of them really helped me...
I want to know how to code a background like this -> http://www.liveandwired.co
with vector shapes and expecially this waves

Has someone an Idea how to make this?
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those shapes are created with `pseudo-elements`.

Here is pen -
https://codepen.io/thesumit67/pen/mwxpzJ

For more CSS Shapes -
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/